# Как проиграть раномный метод, для этого нужно создать массив методов в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, action

Непонимаю почему не добавляется в массив метод выдает ошибку NullReferenceException неправильная ссылка, что не то сотворил?

```
    private List<System.Action> RandomMethod;
    private void Start()
    {
        RandomMethod.Add(Damage);
        RandomMethod.Add(ResourcesFind);
       
    }
    public static  void Damage()
    {
        Debug.Log("1");
     //   PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MyHp",PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MyHp")-10);
    }
    public static void ResourcesFind()
    {
        Debug.Log("2");
        //  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Resources", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Resources") +1);
    }
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        RandomMethod[Random.Range(0, RandomMethod.Count - 2)]();//Выполняем рандомное событие
    }
```

Comment: Вы список-то проинициализировали? В коде этого нет. private List<System.Action> RandomMethod = new List<System.Action>();

Comment: Я думал то при добавление через add, он автоматически инициализируеться, так ли ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы уничтожаете объект

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

А потом пытаетесь у него вызывать другие методы

Comment: Спасибо, я пропустил момент

Comment: @СергейХарланов Пожалуйста! :) Галочка слева от ответа - тык)